# How do you know what CSS name an element is to override it

Tags: css, less

If I see an element such as this in the code, how do I work out what to put in my less file to override the CSS used on it?

button id="bundle-slide" class="action primary customize" type="button"

I believe the background color for this one would be: @button-primary_background

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to magento, this is a CSS/Less only question that would be better suited to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Given that this is specifically about the implementation on a Magento site where the naming of the CSS elements is determined in Magento and guidance on how to determine what name Magento has given to an element I would suggest that 'knowing' or learning how to determine what that name is MUST be a Magento specific issue

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to change background of bundle product button then write down below style in your less file

```
.bundle-actions {
    .action.primary.customize {
        background-color: @button-background;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this was the code I had found. What I do not know is how to determine, from looking at the source code of a page how to work out the various selectors... i.e. are "bundle-actions" and ".action.primary.customize" noted in the HTML/CSS code and if so is there a method for determining what that is from it?

Comment: So, in the code I gave I can see that .action.primary.customize  is identical to the class. But is it just the first word of the ID (without the -slide) followed by '-actions'?